# Performance slowdown when calling object values while retrieving object

Tags: php, performance, web-services

When using the following code which retrieves an object from a webservice I saw a slowdown of roughly .5s after combining the lines.

```
$getChildren = $OKMDocument->getChildren(array('token' => $token, 'path' => $path));
$fileArray = $getChildren->return;
```

to

```
$fileArray = $OKMDocument->getChildren(array('token'=> $token, 'path' => $path))->return;
```

Is there an easy way to identify why this would cause such a performance hit?

Edit:

It is a webservice hosted locally.

```
$OKMAuth = new SoapClient('http://localhost:8080/OpenKM/services/OKMAuth?wsdl');
$OKMDocument = new SoapClient('http://localhost:8080/OpenKM/services/OKMDocument?wsdl');
```

Comment: Does `$WebService->getChildren()` make a remote call (i.e. to a database or some other remote application)? It could simply be latency. I'd try repeated tests of each, and see if the .5s is constant.

Comment: looks like its calling a remote site

Comment: It is a local webservice.

Comment: There is still latency involved in processing the request, so without running multiple tests of each, there is no way to know for sure if the .5s difference is constant, or was simply a momentary spike.

Comment: its using a local path and not a url? really need to sse more code than this.

Comment: The service does maintain a database if you think the issue could be there.

Comment: Without knowing what happens in `$WebService->getChildren(...)` it's really impossible to say what is slowing it down. I don't think it is from the organization of code unless you have this code within a loop structure where it is being executed repeatedly and losing scope. In that case, it could have to do with memory allocation and deallocation.

Comment: It most likely was a simple inconsistency with fetching from the database. Run your test a few more times, and I bet the .5s difference disappears.

Comment: I guess it was just something with the db when I initially tried. I tested it roughly 5 times just refreshing and it was consistently .5s slower but now there is no difference. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an easy way to identify why this would cause such a performance hit?

The tool what you are searching for is called a [profiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29). The most common way to profile PHP applications would be to use the xdebug profiler together with a tool like [wincachegrind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wincachegrind/) or [kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) (linux) what helps you to investigate your program flow and execution times. The GUI will look like this :

[image: GUI of WinCacheGrind]

You should start reading the xdebug [documentation](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) about profiling

Comment: I seriously doubt this "performance hit" is consistent, or even caused by PHP. It's most likely his web service competing for system resources that is causing the inconsistency in execution time, and has nothing to do with his reorganization of code.

Comment: Thank you for the information @hek2mgl although it looks like I was worried for nothing.